# Вызов функции Node.JS виде f(а)(b)

Tags: node.js

решаю типичные HRские задачки по node и встретил условие:
"будет возвращать сумму чисел a и b,но вызываться должна следующим образом : f(a)(b). Например, f(2)(2) —> 4"

Это что за вызов функции - f(a)(b)

Comment: Вызов как вызов. Типичен для [каррированных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) функций, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это значит что первый вызов вернёт функцию:

```js
function sum (a) {
  return function (b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

console.info(sum(5)(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так поддерживается с верии 4.4.5

```js
f = function(a){ return (b) => a + b; }

console.log(f(5)(5));
```

Comment: Тогда уже так:
`f = a => b => a + b;`